# Display content on NSoutlineView from NSTreeNode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview, nstreecontroller

I want to display data in an `NSOutlineView`. I have an `NSTreeNode` with data, but I don't know how to display the contents of the `NSTreeNode` in an `NSOutlineView`.

I have wasted a lot of time googling buy I couldn't found anything which could full-fill my requirement.. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to study the example [DragNDropOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragNDropOutlineView/Introduction/Intro.html), Getting data wrapped inside the NSTreeNode is easy, you simply access to the representedObject property

For example take a look at `(id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item` present in DragNDropOutlineView, where item is an NSTreeNode instance

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn byItem:(id)item {
    id objectValue = nil;
    SimpleNodeData *nodeData = [item representedObject];
 ...
 ...
}
```